# how to pass match option in the request for find method in fortune js adapter

Tags: json, api, get, match

[fortune js](http://fortune.js.org/) library enables the API to be json api compliant. we are using it as middleware on top of core WCF services.

[the find method of the adapter supports option](http://fortune.js.org/api/#adapter-find) argument which allows client to pass in various options such as sort, fields and so on. there is a match option in there which allows client to filter data in the response based on a match criteria.

i would like to know how to pass in a value for this in the http get request. i looked in the [json api specification](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-filtering) but could only find filter query parameter which didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filter query string parameter is the way to go. so request would look like

```
http://url?filter[name]='abc'
```

and in the fortune js adapter you can access it using options as below:

```
find(id,options){
    console.log(options.match.name);
    //filter your response by name
}
```